# Is it important to have images of same dimensions to create a sprite?

Tags: css, svg, sprite

I have been working on a huge project which has around 1000 images and it might even increase too. So, to reduce the number of HTTP requests, I created a few sprites with around 100 images each. But when I use these sprites in the project, the generated scss class properties doesn't do a proper job.

Lets say I have the following generated css for the sprite:

```
.svg-main{
    background: url("sprites/main.sprite.svg") no-repeat;
}

.svg-icon{
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.svg-icon-dims {
    width: 30px;
    height: 33px;
}
.svg-home {
    background-position: 0 7.741935483870968%;
}

.svg-home-dims {
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
}

.svg-info-gray {
    background-position: 0 15.483870967741936%;
}

.svg-info-gray-dims {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
}
```

When, I reference the image, the top of the home gets chopped off and the top part of the info-gray icon shows up. So, the obvious solution would be to correct the padding and the width and height properties explicitly. And I know that this happens because of the uneven dimensions of the images used in the sprite. This problem occurs even when we have all the icons of the same dimensions in one single sprite.

So, how can one tackle such a problem? So, is it important to have the images of the same dimensions when we create a sprite? Are there any other ways to simplify such process.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Note: I am using [svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svg-sprites) for the svg images and [spritesmith](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp.spritesmith) for the png/jpeg images. Task runner - Gulp

Thank you.

Comment: You should already know the size of your images if they are on your Server. If not, then you can use JavaScript AJAX to send the filename to PHP to `getimagesize()`, then change the image size on the Client, with the JavaScript `Element.height = '33'` and `Element.width = '33'`. I recommend keeping the images in their original sizes or resave them as the new size to avoid vector scaling.

Comment: Yes, true. I know the dimensions of my images. But my question is if I have 3 images with dimensions, 20 x 20, 24 x 24, and 54 x 54. When, I create a sprite with these 3 images and use them in my project, they get misaligned and the dimensions change automatically. So, if I need that sprite to be properly aligned in my project, do I need to have all the images used in a sprite to be of same dimensions? or is there an other way around to fix them. As, you said I agree with keeping the images in their original sizes :)   @PHPglue